# Getting stared with GUI programming in JAVA

Tags: java

When I compile the code below in Eclipse, I expect a window to appear with a button on the upper left corner of the window. Instead, the button has the same size as the window and fills the window completely, although I suppose to have restricted the size of the button in line 11 with "button.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 50);". Can anybody tell me what I did wrong or what I forgot?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BeobachterGUI {
   public BeobachterGUI() {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("A frame");
       frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));


       JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
       button.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 50);

       frame.getContentPane().add(button);

       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setResizable(false);
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

       public void run() {   
       new BeobachterGUI();
       }
   });
   }
}
```

Comment: you may want to look into LayoutManagers. But if you're just starting to learn: Swing is an ancient UI framework, why not begin with JavaFX?

Comment: Swing uses a layout manager to place items in a window, and the default layout manager does what you describe. See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to learn about layouts in Swing.

Comment: @KevinAnderson has the right answer. If you want step by step building of a practical application instead of contrived examples I have full source for a book I am writing at https://github.com/markbernard/startinggui. It contains both Swing and Java FX examples.

Comment: @Stultuske Just because JavaFX is newer doesn't make it better. There are advantages to using JavaFX. The main one is performance. But Swing does a number of other things better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JFrame`s automatically give themselves a default `BorderLayout`, which is what is making your button fill the entire screen.  If you want to have direct control over the size and position of your button, you have to get rid of that layout manager.  Use this line of code:

```
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

A word of advice, though: working without a layout manager is OK for fun and experimentation, but you shouldn't make a habit of it.  You'll get a better GUI (and the users of your GUI get a better experience) if you learn to design with layout managers.

To see an example of what I mean, just watch what happens when you resize your window: if you make the window too small, the button can get cut off or hidden completely.  A layout manager would try to reposition and/or resize the button so it stays visible.

Comment: Despite your word of advice, I still wouldn't say to use `null` for the layout.

Comment: @notyou I'd have suggested using a do-nothing layout manager if I knew of one in AWT or Swing.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: problem with a null layout: if you look at your UI on a different screen resolution, chances are bigger you'll get a whole different result.